# Codeigniter creates new session instead of updating old one

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have a cart. I redirect to payment site, then redirect back to my site. When I redirect to my site, it creates a new blank session instead of updating the old one.

However, if I delete all my session records and delete my cookies, when I try a payment and redirect back to my site, the session correctly updates instead of creating a new blank one. It will continue to work properly for a while and then eventually the problem comes back.

Any ideas as to why a new session is being created instead of updating the old one? And any idea why deleting my sessions and cookies fixes that problem for a while?

I have searched many threads and forums and have yet to find an answer that has worked for me.

- Using version 2.0.2 and storing sessions in a database.
- I do autoload sessions

Config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 28800; //7200 - 8 hours for test
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Issue persists with both:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```